# Can I use a 9 V power supply instead of 12 V for my piano keyboard?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a piano keyboard, the manufacturer says that it needs 12 V.
My original mains power supply (adapter) is not working and I only have another 9 V power supply.
Can I use it without risk?
Thank you

Here is an image of both power supplies (adapters):

[image: two mains power supplies]

Comment: You've asked on the wrong site. This one is for electronics *design* questions and use of electronic designs is off-topic so your question will probably be closed soon. It's unlikely that you'll damage the keyboard but the voltage is low so it probably won't work. You'll need to check the polarity of the plug is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your power supply is regulated. If you need regulated (stable) 12V, and the 9V supply is unregulated, it could give you up to 14V or slightly higher when not loaded. Chances are it will work, but we don't know for sure.
You would have to show us the pictures of both and we could give you a better advice.
EDIT: After looking at the picture of your power supplies, it is clear they are both regulated BUT the 9V supply can only give up to 0.6 amperes (amps), while the original 12V supply can give up to 2 amps (2A or 2000mA). Clearly, the 9V supply is significantly under-powered. You may be able to turn the keyboard on, but as soon as you start doing something with it, it will lose power.

Comment: Thank you for your reply l, this is the picture of the both of them: https://ibb.co/4VLTcXT

Comment: Thank you so much... I tried it and it works perfectly .. I hope it will not be damaged in the future

Comment: It shouldn't be. But your power supply may overheat and burn out. Just get a 12V/2A regulated power supply as soon as you can. You could even go with a 2.5A or 3A supply,  to leave some headroom and not overload the supply.

Answer (score 1):

Just get a new power supply that is compatible. You can try but I don't recommend it. Most likely it just does not work properly or at all. However if the polarity is incorrect, then it can be damaged beyond repair.